# How to access 'second' templated object in in C++ std::map

Tags: c++

Hello I am having difficulty with the decision I have made in coding. I am developing a game, and in my game I have treated everything in Object class and object class has two attributes mainly the vital attribute and point attribute. Point attribute somehow need to be in pair of string and int and sometimes float. (I don't use boost:variant I know it could have been much simpler as I have searched on this site) but I don't like to stick to the boost option, I really need to do this without it. So each point attribute object has int and floats on it, for example attack damage which, in my system is of type int, while attack rate is of type float. I came to solution to make a wrapper template class called PointAttribute< T > and this inherits on PABase class so I can make push it on to map without me knowing the type.

Now I am on the big question how do I properly access the second element of map with pair:

```
pair< string , PABase > ?
```

Is it even possible?
I did mine using this code

```
template< typename T >
PointAttribute< T > * Object::getPointAttributes( const string & oname )
{
    PointAttribute< T > * attribute = static_cast< PointAttribute<T>* >( &pointAttributes[ oname ] );
    cout << "Getting value of : " << oname << " value : " << attribute->getCurrentPoints() << endl;
    return attribute;
}
```

I don't know if I am doing everything right. I know I am doing it wrong and I desperately need help on accessing the information from the second.

Actually my codes works but when I retrieved my desired value it returns a float with the wrong value. I've check the value of my point attribute definition and they seem to be loaded properly in my system it just that when I retrieved it returns a value which is of not the actual value I am expecting.

I invoked the function on this way

```
    float attackRange = Object::getPointAttributes<float>( "attackrange" )->getCurrentPoints();
```

EDIT:

Here is my code for PABase and PointAttribute< T >:

```
#ifndef POINTATTRIBUTE_HPP
#define POINTATTRIBUTE_HPP

#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;

#include<string>
using std::string;

#include<memory>
using std::unique_ptr;

#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

namespace esc
{
    class PABase{ public: virtual ~PABase(){} };

    template< typename T >
    class PointAttribute : public PABase
    {

    public:

        PointAttribute();
        virtual ~PointAttribute();

        void setAttributePoints( T );
        T getAttributePoints() const;

        void increaseCurrentPointsBy( T );
        void decreaseCurrentPointsBy( T );
        void setCurrentPointsTo( T );
        T getCurrentPoints() const;

        void increaseMaxPointsBy( T );
        void decreaseMaxPointsBy( T );
        void setMaxPointsTo( T );
        T getMaxPoints() const;

        void increaseBasePointsBy( T );
        void decreaseBasePointsBy( T );
        void setBasePointsTo( T );
        T getBasePoints() const;

        void resetPointAttribute();

    private:

        void init();

        string attributeName;

        T attributePoints;
        T currentPoints;
        T maxPoints;
        T basePoints;
    };


    template< typename T >
    PointAttribute< T >::PointAttribute()
        :
        attributePoints( T() ),
        currentPoints( T() ),
        maxPoints( T() ),
        basePoints( T() )
    {

    }

    template< typename T >
    PointAttribute< T >::~PointAttribute()
    {

    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::setAttributePoints( T p )
    {
        attributePoints = p;
        currentPoints   = p;
        maxPoints       = p;
        basePoints      = T();

        cout << "\n\nAttribute set! " << endl;
        cout << "Attribute points : " << attributePoints << endl;
        cout << "Max points       : " << maxPoints << endl;
        cout << "Base points      : " << basePoints << endl;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline T PointAttribute< T >::getAttributePoints() const
    {
        return attributePoints;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::increaseCurrentPointsBy( T amount )
    {
        currentPoints += amount;
        currentPoints = ( currentPoints > maxPoints )? maxPoints : currentPoints;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::decreaseCurrentPointsBy( T amount )
    {
        currentPoints -= amount;
        currentPoints  = ( currentPoints < T() )? T() : currentPoints;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::setCurrentPointsTo( T amount )
    {
        if( amount >= basePoints && amount <= maxPoints )
            currentPoints = amount;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline T PointAttribute< T >::getCurrentPoints() const
    {
        return currentPoints;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::increaseMaxPointsBy( T amount )
    {
        int checkVal = ( amount < T() )? T() : amount;
        maxPoints += checkVal;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::decreaseMaxPointsBy( T amount )
    {
        T checkVal = ( amount < T() )? T() : amount;
        maxPoints -= checkVal;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::setMaxPointsTo( T amount )
    {
        T checkVal = ( amount < T() )? T() : amount;
        maxPoints = checkVal;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline T PointAttribute< T >::getMaxPoints() const
    {
        return maxPoints;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::increaseBasePointsBy( T amount )
    {
        if( amount > T() && amount <= maxPoints )
            basePoints += amount;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::decreaseBasePointsBy( T amount )
    {
        if( amount > T() && amount <= maxPoints )
            basePoints -= amount;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::setBasePointsTo( T amount )
    {
        if( amount > T() && amount <= maxPoints )
            basePoints = amount;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline T PointAttribute< T >::getBasePoints() const
    {
        return basePoints;
    }

    template< typename T >
    inline void PointAttribute< T >::resetPointAttribute()
    {
        maxPoints  = attributePoints;
        basePoints = T();
    }
}

#endif // POINTATTRIBUTE_HPP
```

Here is how the point attribute is beign filled up before the game begins. The definition is loaded from a simple text file with this given syntax:

```
[pointattribute]
attackdamage 7
attackrange 150
```

and here is the part of the home-made reader I have made, what this does is to read a particular identifier as long it is a valid file symbol, in this case [pointattribute]
the reason is I could add more point attribute in the future without doing a lot of codes and I can just change them freely as I balance the game. (I am writing a framework for RTS).

Here is the snippet for that else-if part of the reader

```
        else if( identifier.compare("[pointattribute]") == 0 )
        {
            string aname;
            string s_eval;

            s >> aname >> s_eval;

            cout << "\n\nLoading point attribute of : " << oname << endl;
            cout << "Attribute name : " << aname << " value : ";

            if( is< float >( s_eval ) )
            {
                istringstream s( s_eval );
                float fval = 0.0f;
                s >> fval;

                PointAttribute< float > wrap;
                wrap.setAttributePoints( fval );

                attrib->pointAttributes[ aname ] = wrap;

                cout << fval << endl;
            }
            else if( is< int >( s_eval ) )
            {
                istringstream s( s_eval );
                int ival = 0;
                s >> ival;

                PointAttribute< int > wrap;
                wrap.setAttributePoints( ival );

                attrib->pointAttributes[ aname ] = wrap;

                cout << ival << endl;
            }
        }
```

The value returned in Object class scope is on around 1.0e something whatever. It just return that kind of real number which is in fact not the value I am expecting. Something is wrong and something I gravely overlooked.

Also I have a young experience in C++ so sorry for my jargons I hope I made myself clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might be useful to add the code for the `PABase` and `PointAttribute` classes. Also I think you should store a pointer to `PABase` instead of objects in your `pair`.

Comment: Of course I am going to post it now...

Comment: Also post the definition of `pointAttributes`, please!

Comment: I actually wanted to that but I don't know, should I just them in the heap? I am instantiating an instance of PointAttribute< T > from some far far away code. And there arrive Object class that needed that definition.

Comment: Your base class class PABase is effective an empty class. There is no point in having objects of empty classes. What you are probably wanting is to put `PABase*` into you map, so that you can stick different types of objects in it, via their pointer. of course, those pointer will be useless without downcasting, and downcasting is a sure sign of bad design.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to declare the virtual destructor for `PointAttribute<T>` again. It's virtual automatically, because the base class has it declared as virtual. You can just completely leave it out.

Comment: `PABase` doesn't seem to do an awful lot. Is there a reason for it being there when the `PointAttribute` template class can handle different data types?

Comment: I rather take it as a bad design. So I'll make a map with pair< string , PABase* >. Thanks for that. Hmm I don't really know what is the magic meter on determining on how much is too bad? I have encountered such problem and diverted from it for instace my Object class which I have re-factored for the past few weeks so I could no longer do downcasting. I think I have just used it here somehow.

Comment: Alright thanks for the info. I'll try to refactor it out, I can't sleep and it's new year, its mind boggling. So this total no-no just like no solution at all. I don't know the reason it return such value. I suspect somehow that is not intiated properly but as you can see, I couted all the values and in different scope where they expected to be there and it just fine just on that invocation that it went horribly wrong. I switch with PABase class and see if the problem goes away. :)

Comment: You can also make a single PointAttribute class and store the value in a union if it's only for POD types. Like `union { int iValue; float fValue; }`.

Comment: how, I don't know that, i haven't tried unions. Oh God. Thanks!!! I'll research on that one. thanks.